# Assign name of data frame to ggplot title in purrr loop

Tags: r, ggplot2, purrr

I have two data sets from which I would like to generate histograms showing how the data overlap by name (A,  B, C). I have written a custom function so I can use ggplot with map2.

I would like the graphs to be titled according to the name of each data set, so "A", "B", "C." Does anyone know of a way to do this?

```
# load packages 
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

## load and format data 1
df1_raw <- data.frame(name = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "C", "B"), 
                 start = c(1, 3, 4, 5, 2, 1),  
                 end = c(6, 5, 7, 8, 6, 7)) 
df1 <- split(x = df1_raw, f = df1_raw$name) # split data by name
df1 <- lapply(df1, function(x) Map(seq.int, x$start, x$end)) # generate sequence intervals
df1 <- map(df1, unlist) # unlist sequences
df1 <- lapply(df1, data.frame) # convert to df

## load and format data 2
df2_raw <- data.frame(name = c("C", "B", "C", "A", "A", "B"), 
                      start = c(5, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5),  
                      end = c(7, 8, 7, 6, 9, 6)) 
df2 <- split(x = df2_raw, f = df2_raw$name) # split data by name
df2 <- lapply(df2, function(x) Map(seq.int, x$start, x$end)) # generate sequence intervals
df2 <- map(df2, unlist) # unlist sequences
df2 <- lapply(df2, data.frame) # convert to df

## write custom ggplot function and generate graphs
gplot <- function(data1, data2) {
  ggplot() + 
    geom_histogram(data = data1, aes(x = X..i..),  binwidth = 1, color = "grey", fill = "grey") +
    geom_histogram(data = data2, aes(x = X..i..),  binwidth = 1, fill = "pink", alpha = 0.7) +
    labs(
      title = ls(data1))
}

hist <- map2(df1, df2, gplot)
```

I also tried the following in the title field in my function:

```
deparse(substitute(data1))
```

Comment: FYI - you need backticks (next to the `1` key), not single quotes, for code-formatting

Comment: Thanks, I was using the wrong character and was really confused about why it wasn't working.

Comment: `deparse(substitute(data1))` is the normal way to do this, but having it inside a `purrr` loop makes things more difficult. Your best bet may be to edit your function to take a `title` argument and add `names(df1)` to the list of arguments you are looping over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another similar option to what @GregorThomas mentioned in the comments, you could add a name variable to your data.frames and pull from that in your `gplot()` function. I've also shown how you might combine a few of your data manipulation steps:

```
# load packages 
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

## load and format data 1
df1_raw <- data.frame(name = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "C", "B"), 
                      start = c(1, 3, 4, 5, 2, 1),  
                      end = c(6, 5, 7, 8, 6, 7)) 
df1 <- df1_raw %>%
  split(.$name) %>% # split data by name
  imap(function(x, x_name) {
    data.frame(value = Map(seq.int, x$start, x$end) %>% unlist,
               name = x_name)
  })

## load and format data 2
df2_raw <- data.frame(name = c("C", "B", "C", "A", "A", "B"), 
                      start = c(5, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5),  
                      end = c(7, 8, 7, 6, 9, 6)) 
df2 <- df2_raw %>%
  split(.$name) %>% # split data by name
  imap(function(x, x_name) {
    data.frame(value = Map(seq.int, x$start, x$end) %>% unlist,
               name = x_name)
  })

## change the title component of your previous function
gplot <- function(data1, data2) {
  ggplot() + 
    geom_histogram(data = data1, aes(x = value),  binwidth = 1, color = "grey", fill = "grey") +
    geom_histogram(data = data2, aes(x = value),  binwidth = 1, fill = "pink", alpha = 0.7) +
    ggtitle(data1$name[1])
}

## plot it
map2(df1, df2, gplot)
```